# tell java location of library

Tags: java, shared-libraries

I compiled a jar that depends on the jhdf5 library, and tried running it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/lib java -classpath ./target/scala-2.11/myassembly.jar -Djava.library.path=$PWD/lib net.myproject.mainClass blah blah blah`

I get an error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jhdf5 (Not found in java.library.path)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1256)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1226)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:537)
    at hdf.hdf5lib.H5.loadH5Lib(H5.java:317)
    at hdf.hdf5lib.H5.<clinit>(H5.java:257)
```

even though the library (libjhdf5.so) is in the directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you running this on windows? or linux?

Comment: under unix (on one of the NERSC systems)

Comment: I suppose then you may be having library compiled for different architecture such 32bit / 64. And it is enough to use one of the variable such as  -Djava.library.path or LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Not both. and are you sure $PWD variable got interpreted correctly?

Comment: I used scala to try and run it, and got a more informative error message that suggested the problem is it can't load functions jhdf5 references in hdf5, which I think might have been caused by the fact that hdf5 is a static library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly make sure native HDF5 c libraries in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64 The program makes use of these native c libraries.

https://github.com/WimS83/XSQConverter/blob/master/src/xsqconvertergit/interfaces/librariesZipped/hdf5_native_libs.zip .

Comment: I'm on a shared system, so I don't have control over the location of the libraries, but I added the path where libhdf5.so is to both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and -Djava.library.path . This doesn't solve the error.

Comment: The issue was that I didn't have shared library versions of the hdf5 libraries, only static versions, while Java was looking for a shared library.